# How to change custom HTML in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I need to rewrite some code on my client's website that I haven't made. The problem is that it runs on wordpress (w/ a customised theme I guess) that I've absolutely no experience with whatsoever.

Where do I find the source code made by that previous developer? I tried to find it in the "wp-admin" page but I failed :D ... where would you edit website's landing page?

Thanks ;)

Comment: Hi, the theme files can be found in /wp-content/themes/_active_theme_name_/  folder.

If the code you want to change is in the upper section, it might be inside header.php

If the code is on lower section, it might be in footer.php

Remember you may not find what you are looking inside theme files. It could be stored in wordpress database too. You will need some very basic knowledge of wordpress post, page, media, widget, theme option, menus to figure it out.


*** Watch some videos on youtube on "Basic wordpress usage"

Answer (score 1):

Depending if the developer wrote a new theme or edited another theme, and if the lather, wether he did it the right way.

Check out the name of your current active theme and you should find it here:

```
/path/to/your/wordpress/installation/wp-content/themes
```

If he altered another theme, there should be another directory named "activeTheme-child". There any changes should be made so you can run updates on the main theme.